# If url contains this folder + random archive

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do the next thing:

```
if (document.referrer=="http://host.com/folder1/*.html"){
    alert('True');
}
```

So what I want to do is to show an alert if the script detects we are on folder1, no matter the archive. The * (asterisk) is to execute it no matter what name it has. But I really don't know how to do it, obviously the example above is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are trying to test if the variable `document.referrer` starts with `http://host.com/folder1`, so you could use the following:

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('http://host.com/folder1')==0){
    alert('True');
}
```

Comment: This one is what I needed. Thanks Amine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (document.referrer.match("http://host.com/folder1/[^/]+\.html"))
```

See here for more:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Here's a jsFiddle you can play with:

- http://jsfiddle.net/BRWkK/

The code is:

```
var ref = "http://host.com/folder1/abc.html";
var ref1 = "http://host.com/folder1/abc.xml";
var ref2 = "http://host.com/folder1/qq/abc.html";

if (ref.match("http://host.com/folder1/[^/]+\.html")) {
    $('#msgs').text('matches!');
} else {
    $('#msgs').text('doesn\'t match...');
}
```

If you use `ref` in `if(...)`, it will match, but `ref1` and `ref2` will not match.

Comment: Very educational. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function and a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
if (/http:\/\/host\.com\/folder1\/.*\.html/.test(document.referrer)){
    alert('True');
}
```

or the [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function:

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf("http://host.com/folder1/") == 0)

    alert('True');
}
```

Note that the second method does not check for the `.html` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add this :

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
    return this.indexOf(str) == 0;
  };
}
```

Then you could do this :

```
if (document.referrer.startsWith("http://host.com/folder1/")){
    alert('True');
}
```